# Value on same place under slider

Tags: javascript

I made a slider that changes value and smiley image on sliding.

In this image the value is always shown in the bottom left corner, like this:

[image: Slider with score 10]

What I want to achieve is something like this:
[image: Slider with value under it]
So when you slide the smiley to the left, the value also slides with it.

My javascript:

```
var slider = document.getElementById("feedback-slider");
var cijfer = document.getElementById("feedback-cijfer");
cijfer.innerHTML = "Uw gekozen cijfer: " + slider.value;


slider.oninput = function() {

 if (slider.value <= 6) {
 slider.classList.add('orange');slider.classList.remove('red');
 } if (slider.value <= 3) {
 slider.classList.add('red');slider.classList.remove('orange');
 } if (slider.value >= 7) {
 slider.classList.remove('red');slider.classList.remove('orange');
 }

 cijfer.innerHTML = "Uw gekozen cijfer: " + this.value;
 }
```

The `if` conditions are to change the color of the smiley.

My HTML:

```
<div class="feedback-container">
 <input type="range" value="10" min="0" max="10" class="feedback-slider" id="feedback-slider">
</div>
<p style="padding-top: 20px;" id="feedback-cijfer"></p>
```

Does anyone know how to position the element with id `feedback-cijfer` to change with the slider?

Comment: So basically when the slider moves on the value also should move ?

Comment: Set text to absolute position of your icon and use css transitionX: -50%. Something along those lines would do it.

Comment: Yep @DILEEPTHOMAS

Comment: @Sybrentjuh Check the answer

Comment: Check this one https://codepen.io/yannicvanveen/pen/HtvbI

Comment: With a few adjustments this works perfectly, thanks!